# Efficiency of passing a struct to a function without instantiating a local variable

Tags: c++, struct, local, pass-by-value

I recently learned that I can do the following with passing a a struct to a function in C++:

(My apologies for not using a more appropriate name for this "feature" in the title, feel free to correct me)

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct mystruct{
    int data1;
    int data2;
} MYSTRUCT;

void myfunction( MYSTRUCT _struct ){
    std::cout << _struct.data1 << _struct.data2;
}

int main(){
    //This is what I recently learned
    myfunction( MYSTRUCT{2,3} );
    return 0;
}
```

This makes me wonder is this less costly than instantiating a local `MYSTRUCT`
and passing it by value to the function? Or is it just a convenient way to do the same only that the temporary variable is eliminated right afterwards?

For example adding this line `#define KBIG 10000000`, is this:

```
std::vector<MYSTRUCT> myvector1;
for (long long i = 0; i < KBIG; i++) {
    myvector1.push_back(MYSTRUCT{ 1,1 });
}
```

Consistently faster than this:

```
std::vector<MYSTRUCT> myvector2;
for (long long i = 0; i < KBIG; i++) {
    MYSTRUCT localstruct = { 1,1 };
    myvector2.push_back(localstruct);
}
```

I tried testing it, but the results were pretty inconsistent, hovering around 9-12 seconds for each. Sometimes the first one would be faster, other times not. Of course, this could be due to all the background processes at the time I was testing.

Comment: So the conclusion is that there is no big performance difference? If you want to know for sure, build with optimization enabled, and compare the generated code for both alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying slightly and compiling to assembler:

```
extern void emit(int);

typedef struct mystruct{
    int data1;
    int data2;
} MYSTRUCT;

__attribute__((noinline))
void myfunction( MYSTRUCT _struct ){
  emit(_struct.data1);
  emit(_struct.data2);
}

int main(){
    //This is what I recently learned
    myfunction( MYSTRUCT{2,3} );
    return 0;
}
```

with -O2 yields:

```
myfunction(mystruct):
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    %rdi, %rbx
        call    emit(int)
        sarq    $32, %rbx
        movq    %rbx, %rdi
        popq    %rbx
        jmp     emit(int)
main:
        movabsq $12884901890, %rdi
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    myfunction(mystruct)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

What happened?

The compiler realised that the entire structure fits into a register and passed it by value that way.

moral of the story: express intent. Let the compiler worry about details.

If you need a copy, you need a copy. End of story.

Answer (score 1):

If speed is of any concern, take measurements of copying vs. taking const ref (i.e., `const MYSTRUCT& _struct`). When you do measurements, make sure you do them <1> <2>, then <2> <1> to compensate for cache effect.

Suggestions: avoid using `_` as the first char of parameter, as some reserved words start with it; also, do not capitalize struct.

Comment: wrong. why do you suppose a reference is faster? you have no knowledge of how the optimiser will approach the code. The resulting assembler often bears no resemblance to the source code.

Comment: Edited: take measurements instead of only taking const ref. That said, there's a reason why we tend to take const refs for real-life objects (I believe OP's example was just that - an example, not a copy of the actual struct. I might be wrong here - a comment from OP would certainly help clearing this.). Not claiming it'll *always* be faster, just that it'd be the first thing I'd check for a real-life struct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up your code, I suggest you to pass the struct via const reference, as follow:

```
void myfunction (const MYSTRUCT& _struct)
{
    std::cout << _struct.data1 << _struct.data2;
}
```

This will be much more faster than passing by value because instead of copying an entire struct, it will pass just its address.

(Ok, there will not be so much difference in this case, since your struct contains only 2 integers, but it you have >1000 bytes (for example) then there will be a notable difference)

Also, i suggest you to use to use `std::vector<T>::emplace_back` instead `std::vector<T>::push_back`

```
std::vector<MYSTRUCT> myvector1;
for (long long i = 0; i < KBIG; i++)
{
    myvector1.emplace_back (1, 1);
}
```

`emplace_back` forwards its arguments to the constructor of `mystruct`, so the compiler will not create an useless copy.

Comment: wrong. this is not "much faster". you cannot reason about the optimisations the compiler will make. express intent and leave it at that.

Comment: 'This will be probably faster' ok?

Comment: In most situations it is.

Comment: in the example code, copy elision will certainly mean that a 'copy' is faster, since the copy is elided and the structure is created inside the function. In addition, copying data once and referring to the copy is often much faster than referencing data via indirection. express intent. leave optimisation to the compiler.